# Architecture for scaling up Electron application development with plugin-style packages

Tags: javascript, architecture, electron

**Background:**
We are developing an electron application which gets bigger and bigger over time. We've separated our web-app (renderer process) and the native wrapper process (main process) into separate projects, which is a good start, but not enough-
We have different teams working on the same electron infrastructure and would like to split the code into separate repos, each managed by a different team, and all of them are being loaded into the main infrastructure project of electron.

**Problem:**
At first, it sounds simple - create an npm package for each electron module (one for each team) and import those packages in the main electron project, that manages all of them and builds the final electron app. The problem is that those electron packages should be familiar with 'electron' package, and should somehow use the same version of this package. Since keeping track of the package the main electron project uses and updating it manually in every module each time we want to increase it's version is bad for scaled up application, we want to be able to sync them in a better way.

**(Bad) solutions I could think of:**
Pass the electron instance from the main electron app to the inner packages (in an `init` function) and use it instead of using the installed 'electron' package. It solves the problem of  syncing electron versions, but when the main app updates the electron version - the packages won't be familiar with it and might break in case of incompatibility.

It sounds like no matter what I do, I can't decouple the projects and they must communicate (manually) to work properly. Is there any architecture design method I'm missing that could help me split one electron projects into multiple ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are created `@our-company/our-product-common` package with common dependencies and configs (`electron`, `typescript`, lint rules, global constants). If we want to update electron or typescript we update versions in `*-common` package.

Or you can create `@our-company/our-product-electron` package which just reexports `electron`.